# How does Drupal Views decide between multiple displays with the same path

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-views

I need to have a Views that is different for different roles.  But, I don't know what will happen when a customer meets the requirements for all the displays for that View.  Which display will she see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're referring to the display within the views: each view display has a position and the displays are loaded according to that position in an ascending sort.  So if you create a page display (which may get a position of 2 since the Default display typically has a position of 1) and then create another page display *after* that, the next page display may get a position of 3.  The customer will be exposed to the position it reaches first (2, provided that they have met the criteria).

If you're referring to the views themselves: views are loaded in order of their view id (vid).  The customer will be exposed to the first one loaded.

Comment: Great.  I'm referring to the displays.  If this works it will save me the trouble of having to do it via a hook :)

Comment: do you know if there's a way of reordering the displays once they are created?

Comment: @DKinzer: you will need to 1) manually update the position in the database (in views_display) or 2) delete and recreate them in the order that you need.